# Cant figure out MySQL PDO update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script designed for updating a users profile on a website I'm developing, and I can't figure it out.
When I click submit on the website, nothing happens, I have a form setup and all, and I get no error messages what-so-ever. I even looked around Google for solutions, but I cannot find any that help.

This works on the same .php file, it doesn't request another. It checks if there is a POST request, then does everything from there... The password thing is optional to the user, and should only do that stuff if something is entered in the password fields. If there is no POST requests, then it will just show the user the form/table with the input boxes and such, which is not the problem.

Any ideas?

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    try
    {
        /*** connect to database ***/
        /*** mysql hostname ***/
        $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

        /*** mysql username ***/
        $mysql_username = 'username';

        /*** mysql password ***/
        $mysql_password = 'password';

        /*** database name ***/
        $mysql_dbname = 'database';

        /*** select the users name from the database ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
        /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

        /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
        $UsrEmail = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $RealName = filter_var($_POST['realname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        /*** prepare the insert ***/
        $updUSR = "UPDATE Users
            SET UsrEmail=?, RealName=?
                WHERE UsrID=".$_SESSION['UsrID']."";
        $stmtu = $dbh->prepare($updUSR);
        $stmtu->bindParam(':email', $UsrEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtu->bindParam(':realname', $RealName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtu->execute(array($UsrEmail,$RealName));
        $stmtu->execute();

        if(isset($_POST['currpass'], $_POST['newpass1'], $_POST['newpass2']))
        {
            /*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
            $currpass = filter_var($_POST['currpass'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $newpass = filter_var($_POST['newpass1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $newpass2 = filter_var($_POST['newpass2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            /*** verify if the passwords match ***/
            if($newpass == $newpass2)
            {
                /*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
                $UsrPasswd = sha1( $newpass );
                $updPW = "UPDATE Users
                    SET UsrPasswd=?
                        WHERE UsrID=".$_SESSION['UsrID']."";
                $stmtp->bindParam(':newpass', $UsrPasswd, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
                $stmtp = $dbh->prepare($updPW);
                $stmtp->execute(array($UsrPasswd));
                $stmtp->execute();
            }
            else
            {
                $message = "The passwords entered do not match, please try again.";
            }
        }

        /*** if all is done, say thanks ***/
        $message = 'Profile Settings Changed Successfully';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong ***/
        $message = 'We are unable to process your request.<br />Please try again later.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Concatenating strings into the query defeats the purpose of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, I corrected some of them in this part:

```
    $UsrEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $RealName = $_POST['realname'];

    /*** prepare the insert ***/
    $updUSR = "UPDATE Users SET UsrEmail=?, RealName=? WHERE UsrID=?";
    $stmtu = $dbh->prepare($updUSR);
    $stmtu->bindParam(1, $UsrEmail);
    $stmtu->bindParam(2, $RealName);
    $stmtu->bindParam(3, $_SESSION['UsrID']);
    $stmtu->execute();
```

if you use question mark placeholders, then, you must use `bindParam(1, $UsrEmail)` not `bindParam(":email", $UsrEmail)`, also, no need to pass array inside `execute`

Comment: This was a fast response! Unfortunately though, it's still the same, it doesn't update the database :( There are no error messages, it just returns to the form, as if it didn't process the PDO at all. I looked over the entire code, and I really don't see anything that could be an issue.

Comment: Oh, nevermind that, I found out it was an issue with the form. Thank you very much!